# The most efficient way to calculate geospatial distances between many points?

Tags: python, bigdata, geospatial

I have two datasets, one describing locations and second having various points:

```
locations.head()
  latitude  longitude  geobounds_lon1  geobounds_lat1  geobounds_lon2  geobounds_lat2
0  52.5054   13.33320        13.08830         52.6755         13.7611         52.3382      
1  54.6192    9.99778         7.86496         55.0581         11.3129         53.3608     
2  41.6671  -71.27420       -71.90730         42.0188        -71.0886         41.0958    
3  25.9859  -80.12280       -87.81370         30.9964        -78.9917         24.5071   
4  43.7004   11.51330         9.63364         44.5102         12.4104         42.1654     

points.head()
   category        lat        lon
0       161  47.923132  11.507743 
1       161  47.926479  11.531736 
2       161  47.943670  11.576099   
3       161  57.617577  12.040591  
4        23  52.124071  -0.491918
```

I need to calculate distances from each offer (based on `locations.latitude` and `locations.longitude`) to every point of each category (for example, `161`). For me, only matters these points that are not so far away from location - I thought that using boundaries of location might be helpful, so I wouldn't need to calculate all distances and then filter them.

The biggest problem for me is how to effectively filter points for every location (based on category and boundaries) and calculate distances to these points from location point as the data counts are quite big (there are almost 9 million rows in locations and more than 10 million rows in points).

For distance calculation I tried `BallTree`:

```
RADIANT_TO_KM_CONSTANT = 6367

class BallTreeIndex:
    def __init__(self,lat_longs):
        self.lat_longs = np.radians(lat_longs)
        self.ball_tree_index = BallTree(self.lat_longs, leaf_size=40, metric='haversine')

    def query_radius(self,query,radius):
        radius_radiant = radius / RADIANT_TO_KM_CONSTANT 
        query = np.radians(np.array([query]))
        result = self.ball_tree_index.query_radius(query, r=radius_radiant,
                                                return_distance=True) 
        return result[1][0]
```

And for filtering points:

```
condition = (points.category == c) & (points.lat > lat2) & (points.lat < lat1) & (points.lon < lon2) & (points.lon > lon1)
tmp = points[condition]
```

where `c` is the specific category, `lat1`, `lat2`, `lon1`, `lon2` are the location boundaries.
However, this would take a lot of time, so I wonder if there is any way to make it faster.

I would like to have a new column in locations dataframe, for example:

```
                    distances_161
0 [distance0_0, distance0_1, ...]
1 [distance1_0, distance1_1, ...]
2 [distance2_1, distance2_2, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain that this is what you want, but it seems to make sense to me.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

def haversine_np(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)

    All args must be of equal length.    

    """
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = np.sin(dlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2.0)**2

    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    km = 6367 * c
    return km




df = {'lon1': [40.7454513], 
'lat1': [-73.9536799], 
'lon2': [40.7060268], 
'lat2': [-74.0110188]}
df


df['distance'] = haversine_np(df['lon1'],df['lat1'],df['lon2'],df['lat2'])
```

Result:

```
array([6.48545403])
```

[image]

So, Python is saying 6.485 miles and Google says 6.5 miles.